# Get url from updated JSBIN IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jsbin

I have an iframe with a jsbin url. When I edit the jsbin, is there any possible way to obtain the upgraded url, without taking it from the jsbin interface.

For example,

I have my iframe with jsbin. I work some stuff on it, and the url of the jsbin  changes in order to save my work. How with javascript can I retrieve the upgraded url?

------HTML

```
<div><iframe id="myframe" class='iframeSize'  src="www.jsbin.com/fafda/1/edit" ></iframe></div>;
```

------javascript

```
var updatedLInk = $("#myframe").attr("src");
```

When I edit the jsbin the link changes because it stores information, however, when I want to retrieve the updatedLInk, I only get the original link like www.jsbin.com/fafda/1/edit instead of www.jsbin.com/fafda/8/edit

Comment: you need to be more clear.Give some code samples.Or upload a screenshot (like in Imgur) and share it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 
`<iframe id="myframe" class='iframeSize'  src="www.jsbin.com/fafda/latest" >`

in order to always display the latest version of your jsbin.

Also if at any time you need to figure out the url you can request the `latest` url 
i.e. `www.jsbin.com/fafda/latest` 
from your server side code (to avoid cross domain issues from client side js) and read the last location redirected.